# Command not found on bash function call

Tags: bash, shell, date

Hi i'm new to bash scripting but cannot understand why i get the *command not found* error when i try to assign to a local variable the result of this function call with parameters 20120920 5.

```
    #!/bin/bash

function nDaysAgo () #date # daysago
{
 date -d "${1} - ${2} days" +%Y%m%d;
}
```

so the script name is ndaysago, i'm first invoking the script with . ndaysago and then assigning the value like this:

```
newdate= nDaysAgo 20120910 5
```

it prints: 20120905: command not found

Meaning that the date execution is made but then tries to use the output as command, thats not what i would expect.

i have also tried assigning the new value to a variable within the function like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

function nDaysAgo () #date # daysago
{
 var=$(date -d "${1} - ${2} days" +%Y%m%d)
}
```

but still nothing, mmmmmm

Comment: i can't reproduce your error!

Comment: check if something else get wrong!

Comment: I assume your original code is actually `newdate=nDaysAgo 20120910 5`, because with the space after the `=` there is no error, you get the correct value _printed_, and nothing in `newdate`.

Comment: this is how i'm trying to assign the value now: newdate=$(nDaysAgo 20120910 5)

Comment: @lanzz you are right. `newdate=nDaysAgo 20120910 5` will get error, and @dogbane is the right answer!

Comment: @lanzz i was wrong. `newdate=nDaysAgo 20120910 5` will get `20120910: command not found` instead of `20120905: command not found`, so i still can not reproduce the error!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spaces are not allowed around the `=` when assigning a variable. To invoke a function you should use the  `$(...)` syntax which is called [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).

Change to:

```
newdate=$(nDaysAgo 20120910 5)
```

Comment: newdate=$(nDaysAgo 20120910 5)  20120905: command not found

Comment: it works for me. Did you remove the space? Use exactly what I wrote.

Comment: are you doing something with `newdate` afterwards? It's probably failing somewhere else.

Comment: I have verified that @dogbane's solution works, you're probably copying it wrong.

Comment: thx but no, the assignment is the same dogbane uses i will copy paste what i have on my shell: username@machine-vm1:~/tests/dates$ newdate=$(nDaysAgo 20120910 5)
20120905: command not found

Comment: @JBoy In this case, your `nDaysAgo` function is different from both variants you have posted.

Comment: @lanzz, no sorry, the function is exactly the same as the first variant in my header: function nDaysAgo () #date # daysago
{
 date -d "${1} - ${2} days" +%Y%m%d;
}

Comment: @JBoy It looks like you have sourced this function into your shell. Can you run `declare -f nDaysAgo` in your shell and confirm that the function is indeed correct?

Comment: @dropgbane, thx for that, i indeed see a different version... how to change it?                                                   nDaysAgo ()
{
    newdate= $(date -d "${1} - ${2} days" +%Y%m%d)
}

Comment: You need to source your `ndaysago` script every time you modify it (`. ndaysago`)

Comment: thx @dogbane @ lanzz, i thought that modifying the function was enough, i did not know that the script needs to be called everytime after modifications.