# bash command not found when setting a variable

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, zsh

I am writing a shell script where I am setting few variables, whose value is the output of commands.

The errors I get are:

```
$  $tag_name="proddeploy-$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M")"
-bash: =proddeploy-20141003_0500: command not found
```

now, I did read [other similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616623/command-not-found-on-bash-function-call) and based on it, I tried various things:

#### spliting command into two calls

```
$ $deploy_date=date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M"
bash: =date: command not found
$ $tag_name="proddeploy-$deploy_date"
bash: proddeploy- command not found
```

#### tried using backticks

```
$ $tag_name=`proddeploy-$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M")`
bash: proddeploy-20141003_1734: command not found
bash: =: command not found
```

#### tried using `$()`

```
$ $tag_name=$(proddeploy-$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M"))
bash: proddeploy-20141003_1735: command not found
bash: =: command not found
```

But in every case the command output is getting executed. how do I make it to stop executing command output and just store as a variable? I need this to work on ZSH and BASH.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You define variables with `var=string` or `var=$(command)`.

So you have to remove the leading `$` and any other signs around `=`:

```
tag_name="proddeploy-$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M")"

deploy_date=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M")
            ^^                   ^
```

From [Command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst):

> The second form `` `COMMAND` `` is more or less obsolete for Bash, since it
>   has some trouble with nesting ("inner" backticks need to be escaped)
>   and escaping characters. Use `$(COMMAND)`, it's also POSIX!

Also, `$()` allows you to nest, which may be handy.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer shows corrected code, but does not clarify that one of your problems is accessing a variable (using $) while assigning it, which is illegal.
For example:

```
$foo=4
```

should be

```
foo=4
```

See the difference? foo is being assigned, so you should not use $foo, which is not foo but the value of foo.