# "Attempted assignment to a non-variable" in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm new to Bash and I've been having issues with creating a script. What this script does is take numbers and add them to a total. However, I can't get total to work.It constantly claims that total is a non-variable despite it being assigned earlier in the program.

error message (8 is an example number being entered)

```
./adder: line 16: 0 = 0 + 8: attempted assignment to non-variable (error token is "= 0 + 8")
```

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
total=0
count=0


while [[ $choice != 0 ]]; do

    echo Please enter a number or 0 to quit

    read choice

    if [[ $choice != 0 ]];
    then
        $(($total = $total + $choice))

        $(($count = $count + 1))


        echo Total is $total
        echo
        echo Total is derived from $count numbers

    fi

done


exit 0
```

Comment: This is closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178654/bash-command-not-found-when-setting-a-variable; I'm surprised it's as hard as it is to find an outright duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of some of the dollar signs in front of the variable names. They're optional inside of an arithmetic context, which is what `((...))` is. On the left-hand side of an assignment they're not just optional, they're forbidden, because `=` needs the variable name on the left rather than its value.

Also `$((...))` should be plain `((...))` without the leading dollar sign. The dollar sign will capture the result of the expression and try to run it as a command. It'll try to run a command named `0` or `5` or whatever the computed value is.

You can write:

```
((total = $total + $choice))
((count = $count + 1))
```

or:

```
((total = total + choice))
((count = count + 1))
```

or even:

```
((total += choice))
((count += 1))
```